# Is there a difference between the ways of defining a Ruby class method?

Tags: ruby, class-method

Given the following two ways of defining a class method in Ruby:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def bar
      # ...
    end
  end

  def self.baz
    # ...
  end
end
```

Is there a difference between the two? Is one more preferable than the other?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881821

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: no and no.

It comes down to personal preference. The first version saves you typing if you define many class methods. The second one may be preferable if you dislike the obscurer syntax of the first.

Comment: I guess the 15 character limit is to stop people like me just typing 'lol'

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'd figured. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify the terminology: there is no such thing as a "class method" in Ruby. What you are doing is to define a *singleton method* on the *object* that is the class `Foo` (remember, classes are objects, too, just like any other). In turn, singleton methods don't really exist, either, they are just normal instance methods on the *eigenclass* (commonly referred to as `Foo′`) of the object, which in this case is also the metaclass of the class `Foo`.

Confused yet? :-)

Basically, there is no difference between doing this:

```
foo = Object.new
class << foo
  def bar
    # ...
  end
end

def foo.baz
  # ...
end
```

and this:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def bar
      # ...
    end
  end

  def self.baz
    # ...
  end
end
```

Because inside a class definition, `self` is bound to the class object (in this case `Foo`), that is equivalent to:

```
class Foo
  class << Foo
    def bar
      # ...
    end
  end

  def Foo.baz
    # ...
  end
end
```

Which is in turn equivalent to:

```
Foo = Class.new
class << Foo
  def bar
    # ...
  end
end

def Foo.baz
  # ...
end
```

Which as you can see is pretty much exactly the same as my first example. This shows that there really is no difference between a singleton method on a class method and a singleton method on any other kind of object, therefore it doesn't make sense to talk about "class methods" in Ruby.

You can also see how these two notations relate to the notion of singleton methods and eigenclasses:

```
def foo.baz
  # ...
end
```

says "add the singleton method `baz` to the object `foo`" and

```
class << foo
  def bar
    # ...
  end
end
```

"open up the eigenclass of object `foo` and then add instance method `bar` to the eigenclass". But, as we established earlier, a singleton method of the object and an instance method of the object's eigenclass are really the same thing. That's why it wouldn't make sense for those two notations to behave differently.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to discourage the term "class methods": the name does not conflict with anything. These methods are indeed just instance methods on metaclasses. But they are quite commonly referred to as class methods in Ruby, including nearly all (core) Ruby documentation. In daily use they are identical to class methods (static methods) in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

As molf said, there's no effective difference. But IMO, the second is so much more skimmable -- it's too easy to miss the `class<<self` and think you're still looking at instance methods. I only tend to use the `class<<self` route when I need more dynamic behavior, such as making `attr_accessor` properties of the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. will get you into trouble if you've got a lots of lines of code between `class << self` and the corresponding `end`. If you don't notic that a method has been defined inside the `class << self` block, you might think its just an instance method.

Option 2. is more typing, more expressive and more understandable to the untrained Ruby-eye.

Theyre's no difference in the end-result as others have pointed already.